# Progress 4GL - Pagination

Tags: pagination, progress-4gl

In PHP and MySQL I can do pagination of data like this:

```
select * from customers LIMIT $start, $limit;
```

The result will return me the page I'm requesting. Is it possible to do something like this using Progress 4GL?

- I do not use -> `select from customers`
- I use -> `for each customers`

But how can I set a limit and pages for that query search?

Example of the pagination:

I have 20.000 customers in my database. In each search I made, I want to separate the result. The limit I want to sent to the application is 100 rows of 1000. And when the user press page 2, it returns another 100 (but not the old 100) rows.

Does that make sense?

---

UPDATE

I'm using a technology from Adobe called Flex. The language Flex does not connect to the database directly, it depends on a back end language to do that.

So I'm using Flex and Progress 4GL. My flex application has a datagrid (like browser in 4GL) to show the data retrieved from my 4GL database.

The problem is that the database is huge, so I need to paginate the data. Each time the user clicks on another page, the Flex application has to communicate with Progress 4GL to retrieve the other page data. But, each click of the button is a different call so the Progress won't have any knowledge of the previous query.

How can I go from the 1st page to the 7th using a query?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific as there are many ways to do what you want, and the solution depends on the specific context of what you're doing and it's requirements.

Comment: hi Tim, thanks for answering. I have updated the topic. If you could please take a look now.

Comment: A query would be the way to go. I've added a link to a Progress KB for batching records to dotNet code, which I think'll assist you with your flex application.

Comment: There are a few ways. easiest would be to use a start value and a count. break after count reached. Then if you want to get next block call same code with new starting value (which will be > then last value from previous result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this KB article on batching records to a .NET client
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000033965?q=query+batch&l=en_US&c=Product_Group%3AOpenEdge&type=Article__kav&fs=Search&pn=1

Comment: Thanks for answering Tim. In the .p file, a query is defined and then opened: OPEN QUERY lvQuery FOR EACH Customer NO-LOCK. But the flex application will call this .p file each time the users click the button. As my dataset is large, wouldn't consume a large mount of time to do: "for each customer" everytime i request this .p file?

Comment: Unlike SQL, progress queries aren't fully resolved when the query is opened. The db engine'll find records as they're needed.

Comment: Got it! But, seeing the code it appears that limited the amount of data that will return and when is requested it brings the next page. But what if i'm in the page 2 and want to go to the 7? How can i set that?

Comment: You'll need to either calculate the offset to get the to start of page 7, or read through the in-between records in order to get there.Fortunately Progress queries are pretty quick if they're given a good index to follow. Also, if this is the answer you're looking for, you need to mark it and give it an upvote pls and thx!

Comment: Yes, i'll vote for you answer. Just one more thing, please. If i get the ROWID of the last register of my browser then i can set something like: "REPOSITION q1 TO ROWID r-rowid NO-ERROR.
REPOSITION q1 FORWARD 50." That 50 represents 5 pages if i set 10 register per page. But your first tip was to alculate the offset, how can i do that and then set the query to go right to the page? It seems more fast this way.

Comment: It depends on your data and your browse requirements. If there's a way to calculate  the next batch of records then you can do that, use FIND to get the record, and then use REPOSITION to move the query in it's result list. If this is not needed or possible, then use the REPOSITION-FORWARD() method.

Comment: This is a link-only answer and thus low quality.  Please copy over the important technical details in case the link goes dead.

Comment: A link-only answer that gives the questioner the desired answer is not low-quality. Copying the "important technical details" in this case would require extracting and copying code from the KB, which is plagiarism and (I presume) is against SE policy.

Comment: if you use dynamic query, there is BATCH-SIZE option